# 'Not Null' syntax error on Decimal and Integer data types

Tags: mysql, sql, decimal

I am getting this error when trying to build the schema in SQL Fiddle. Any suggestions on resolving this issue? Here is the image for more info.

[image: SQL Error]

Comment: Check constraints don't work in mysql

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does not *implement* check constraints, but it does support the syntax.  For an actual check for this purpose, you are advised to use a trigger, a foreign key reference, or an enumerated type.

However, the syntax calls for the `NOT NULL` to appear *before* the constraint:

```
status varchar(8) not null check (status in ('Approved', 'Pending', 'Denied'))
```

The syntax is explained in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html) for `create table`.

Comment: As I read the syntax, there should be a comma before `check` and `check` is not associated with any column.

Comment: @RickJames . . . That would be a separate syntax for constraints that are not part of column definitions.

Answer (score -1):

No.  The error is right at the first `NOT NULL`.  In particular it is complaining about `CHECK(...)`<strike>, which does not exist in MySQL</strike>.

You will soon find that `FOREIGN KEY` requires a `REFERENCES` clause.  [Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html).

Please check all aspects of your syntax with the reference manual.

Comment: Errr . . . MySQL *parses* `check` and check constraints.  It just odesn't implement them.  I think the syntax diagrams are pretty clear on this point:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html.